# Validate an IP Address and am having trouble

Tags: xml, vb.net, validation, ip-address

I'm having trouble with validating an IP address. I am trying to validate it by breaking up the IP address into it's 4 segments and validating each of them separately although I can't figure out how to break it up into the segments.

I've put the entire code below and I will put another code block with only the things relevant to the validation below the one with the entire code

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Ticket_Request_Form
    Dim myXMLFile = "Tickets.xml"
    Public strName As String
    Public strProblem As String
    Public strDateProblemStarted As String
    Public strProblemDescription As String
    Public strTypeOfProblem As String
    Public strIPAddress As String
    Public intIPSegment1 As Integer
    Public intIPSegment2 As Integer
    Public intIPSegment3 As Integer
    Public intIPSegment4 As Integer
    Public blnAllInputsValid As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Ticket_Request_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(myXMLFile) = True Then
            DsTickets.ReadXml(myXMLFile)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TicketsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TicketsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        DtabTicketsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Try
            DsTickets.WriteXml(myXMLFile)
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully", "File Saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Data Not Saved to Tickets.xml", "File Save Error")
        End Try
        strName = txtName.Text
        strProblem = txtProblem.Text
        strDateProblemStarted = txtDateProblemStarted.Text
        strProblemDescription = txtProblemDescription.Text
        strIPAddress = txtIPAddress.Text
        blnAllInputsValid = False
        ValidateUserInputs()
        If blnAllInputsValid <> True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        DtabTicketsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Try
            DsTickets.WriteXml(myXMLFile)
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully", "File Saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Data Not Saved to Tickets.xml", "File Save Error")
        End Try
        ValidateUserInputs()
        If blnAllInputsValid <> True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        DtabTicketsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Try
            DsTickets.WriteXml(myXMLFile)
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully", "File Saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Data Not Saved to ModLibrary.xml", "File Save Error")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click
        Dim confirm_msg As Integer
        confirm_msg = MessageBox.Show("DELETE RECORD FOR " & txtProblem.Text & "?",
                                      "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                      MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        If confirm_msg = vbYes Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Marked for Deletion." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Click the Save Icon to Save Changes" & vbCrLf _
                            & "and Permanently Delete the Record. ", "Delete in Progress")
        Else
            Me.Controls.Clear()
            InitializeComponent()
            Ticket_Request_Form_Load(e, e)
            MessageBox.Show("Record Delete Cancelled." & vbCrLf _
                            & "File Returned to First Record.", "Delete Cancelled")
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub ValidateUserInputs()
        blnAllInputsValid = False
        If strName.Length > 0 Then

        Else
            blnAllInputsValid = False
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your name into the Name Box.", "Input Error")
            txtName.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If strProblem.Length > 0 Then

        Else
            blnAllInputsValid = False
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the problem your having into the Problem box.", "Input Error")
            txtProblem.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If strProblemDescription.Length > 0 Then

        Else
            blnAllInputsValid = False
            MessageBox.Show("Please describe the problem your having into the Problem Description box.", "Input Error")
            txtProblem.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim strUserInputDateProblemStarted As String = txtDateProblemStarted.Text
        Dim strInputDateProblemStartedName As String = "Creation Date"
        Dim blnDateProblemStartedIsValid As Boolean = False

        blnDateProblemStartedIsValid = ValidInputDateProblemStartedCheck(strUserInputDateProblemStarted, strInputDateProblemStartedName)

        If blnDateProblemStartedIsValid = False Then
            txtDateProblemStarted.Focus()
            blnAllInputsValid = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim CurrentDate As Date = Date.Now
        CurrentDate = CurrentDate.ToShortDateString
        If strDateProblemStarted > CurrentDate Then
            MessageBox.Show("Date of Creation Error: " & strUserInputDateProblemStarted & "." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Date cannot be in the Future. " & vbCrLf _
                            & "Current Date Today is: " & CurrentDate & vbCrLf _
                            & "Re-enter the creation date. ", "Date Error")
            txtDateProblemStarted.Focus()
            blnAllInputsValid = False
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim strUserInputIPAddress As String = txtIPAddress.Text
        Dim strInputIPAddressName As String = "IP Address"
        Dim blnIPAddressIsValid As Boolean = False

        blnIPAddressIsValid = ValidInputIPAddressCheck(strUserInputIPAddress, strInputIPAddressName)

        If blnIPAddressIsValid = False Then
            txtIPAddress.Focus()
            blnAllInputsValid = False
            Exit Sub
        End If

        blnAllInputsValid = True
    End Sub
    Public Function ValidInputDateProblemStartedCheck(ByVal strIncomingDateProblemStarted As String, ByVal strIncomingName As String) As Boolean
        If strIncomingDateProblemStarted = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter " & strIncomingName, "Data Missing")
            ValidInputDateProblemStartedCheck = False
            Return ValidInputDateProblemStartedCheck
        End If

        Dim ValidDateProblemStartedFormat As New Regex("\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}")

        If ValidDateProblemStartedFormat.IsMatch(strIncomingDateProblemStarted) Then

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date Format Detected for " & strIncomingName & "." _
                            & vbCrLf & "The date that the problem started should be 10 characters lond." _
                            & vbCrLf & "Date should use - as the seperator symbol." _
                            & vbCrLf & "Required Date Format is dd-mm-yyyy" _
                            & vbCrLf & "Enter Date like this: 10-07-2006.", "Date Problem Started Format Error")
            ValidInputDateProblemStartedCheck = False
            Return ValidInputDateProblemStartedCheck
        End If

        If IsDate(strIncomingDateProblemStarted) Then

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date Error: " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Date is not a Real Date." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Rejecter Date = " & strIncomingDateProblemStarted, "Date Error")
            ValidInputDateProblemStartedCheck = False
            Return ValidInputDateProblemStartedCheck
        End If

        ValidInputDateProblemStartedCheck = True
        Return ValidInputDateProblemStartedCheck
    End Function

    Private Sub btnReviewTicket_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReviewTicket.Click
        txtReviewTicket.Text = "Hi " & txtName.Text & vbCrLf &
        "Problem: " & txtProblem.Text & vbCrLf &
        "Description: " & txtProblemDescription.Text & vbCrLf &
        "The problem has been around since: " & txtDateProblemStarted.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub imgOpen###########_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles imgOpen###########.Click
        Process.Start("https://############################")
    End Sub

    Public Function ValidInputIPAddressCheck(ByVal strIncomingIPAddress As String, ByVal strIncomingName As String) As Boolean
        If strIncomingIPAddress = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter " & strIncomingName, "Data Missing")
            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
            Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
        End If

        If 0 < intIPSegment1 < 255 Then

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP Error: " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf _
                            & "IP is not valid." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Rejected IP Segment = " & intIPSegment1, "IP Address Error")
            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
            Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
        End If

        If 0 < intIPSegment2 < 255 Then

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP Error: " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf _
                            & "IP is not valid." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Rejected IP Segment = " & intIPSegment2, "IP Address Error")
            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
            Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
        End If

        If 0 < intIPSegment3 < 255 Then

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP Error: " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf _
                            & "IP is not valid." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Rejected IP Segment = " & intIPSegment3, "IP Address Error")
            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
            Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
        End If

        If 0 < intIPSegment4 < 255 Then

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP Error: " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf _
                            & "IP is not valid." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Rejected IP Segment = " & intIPSegment4, "IP Address Error")
            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
            Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
        End If

        ValidInputIPAddressCheck = True
        Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
    End Function
End Class
```

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Ticket_Request_Form
    Dim myXMLFile = "Tickets.xml"
    Public strIPAddress As String
    Public intIPSegment1 As Integer
    Public intIPSegment2 As Integer
    Public intIPSegment3 As Integer
    Public intIPSegment4 As Integer
    Public blnAllInputsValid As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Ticket_Request_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(myXMLFile) = True Then
            DsTickets.ReadXml(myXMLFile)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TicketsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TicketsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        DtabTicketsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Try
            DsTickets.WriteXml(myXMLFile)
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully", "File Saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Data Not Saved to Tickets.xml", "File Save Error")
        End Try
        strIPAddress = txtIPAddress.Text
        blnAllInputsValid = False
        ValidateUserInputs()
        If blnAllInputsValid <> True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        DtabTicketsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Try
            DsTickets.WriteXml(myXMLFile)
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully", "File Saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Data Not Saved to Tickets.xml", "File Save Error")
        End Try
        ValidateUserInputs()
        If blnAllInputsValid <> True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        DtabTicketsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Try
            DsTickets.WriteXml(myXMLFile)
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully", "File Saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Data Not Saved to ModLibrary.xml", "File Save Error")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click
        Dim confirm_msg As Integer
        confirm_msg = MessageBox.Show("DELETE RECORD FOR " & txtProblem.Text & "?",
                                      "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                      MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        If confirm_msg = vbYes Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Marked for Deletion." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Click the Save Icon to Save Changes" & vbCrLf _
                            & "and Permanently Delete the Record. ", "Delete in Progress")
        Else
            Me.Controls.Clear()
            InitializeComponent()
            Ticket_Request_Form_Load(e, e)
            MessageBox.Show("Record Delete Cancelled." & vbCrLf _
                            & "File Returned to First Record.", "Delete Cancelled")
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub ValidateUserInputs()
        blnAllInputsValid = False

        Dim strUserInputIPAddress As String = txtIPAddress.Text
        Dim strInputIPAddressName As String = "IP Address"
        Dim blnIPAddressIsValid As Boolean = False

        blnIPAddressIsValid = ValidInputIPAddressCheck(strUserInputIPAddress, strInputIPAddressName)

        If blnIPAddressIsValid = False Then
            txtIPAddress.Focus()
            blnAllInputsValid = False
            Exit Sub
        End If

        blnAllInputsValid = True
    End Sub

    Public Function ValidInputIPAddressCheck(ByVal strIncomingIPAddress As String, ByVal strIncomingName As String) As Boolean
        If strIncomingIPAddress = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter " & strIncomingName, "Data Missing")
            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
            Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
        End If

        If 0 < intIPSegment1 < 255 Then

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP Error: " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf _
                            & "IP is not valid." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Rejected IP Segment = " & intIPSegment1, "IP Address Error")
            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
            Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
        End If

        If 0 < intIPSegment2 < 255 Then

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP Error: " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf _
                            & "IP is not valid." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Rejected IP Segment = " & intIPSegment2, "IP Address Error")
            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
            Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
        End If

        If 0 < intIPSegment3 < 255 Then

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP Error: " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf _
                            & "IP is not valid." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Rejected IP Segment = " & intIPSegment3, "IP Address Error")
            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
            Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
        End If

        If 0 < intIPSegment4 < 255 Then

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP Error: " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf _
                            & "IP is not valid." & vbCrLf _
                            & "Rejected IP Segment = " & intIPSegment4, "IP Address Error")
            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
            Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
        End If

        ValidInputIPAddressCheck = True
        Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
    End Function
End Class
```

If anyone knows how I could go about separating the IP address into the variables intIPSegment1, intIPSegment2, intIPSegment3 and intIPSegment4 any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Axiden

Comment: The [`IPAddress.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-net-ipaddress-tryparse(system-string-system-net-ipaddress@)) method will do it in one line of code.

Comment: If you want to identify where the err or is, `String.Split` and `Byte.TryParse` should be your next ports of call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I validated the IP address (credit given to @EtienneLaneville) this is just slightly edited to work with my code.

```
Public Function ValidInputIPAddressCheck(ByVal strIncomingIPAddress As String, ByVal strIncomingName As String) As Boolean
        If strIPAddress = "-" Then

        Else
            If strIncomingIPAddress = Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter " & strIncomingName, "Data Missing")
                ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
                Return ValidInputIPAddressCheck
            End If

            If strIPAddress.Contains(".") Then

                Dim octets As String() = Strings.Split(strIPAddress, ".")

                If octets.Length = 4 Then

                    For Each octet As String In octets
                        ' Validate value
                        Dim value As Integer = CType(octet, Integer)

                        If value >= 0 And value <= 255 Then
                            ' Valid octet
                        Else
                            ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
                            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP Address Format Detected for " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf &
                                            "Please ensure that all the IP segment are between 0 and 255.", "IP Address Format Error")
                            txtName.Focus()
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    Next
                Else
                    ValidInputIPAddressCheck = False
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP Address Format Detected for " & strIncomingName & "." & vbCrLf &
                                    "Please ensure there are 4 IP segments and not.", "IP Address Format Error")
                    txtName.Focus()
                    Exit Function
                End If

            Else
                ' Octets not separated by periods
            End If
        End If

        ValidInputIPAddressCheck = True
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Strings.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split?view=net-7.0) to break your IP address down into 4 octets that you can then validate:

```
Dim ipAddress As String = "127.0.0.1"

' Check for "localhost"
If Strings.StrComp(ipAddress, "localhost", CompareMethod.Text) = 0 Then
    ipAddress = "127.0.0.1"
End If

If ipAddress.Contains(".") Then

    Dim octets As String() = Strings.Split(ipAddress, ".")

    If octets.Length = 4 Then

        For Each octet As String In octets
            ' Validate value
            Dim value As Integer = CType(octet, Integer)

            If value >= 0 And value <= 255 Then
                ' Valid octet
            Else
                ' Invalid octet
            End If
        Next
    Else
        ' Incorrect number of octets
    End If

Else
    ' Octets not separated by periods
End If
```

Since you want to indicate which octet is incorrect in your original code, you can use a `For` loop instead of a `For Each` loop:

```
For octet As Integer = 1 To octets.Length

    ' Validate value
    Dim value As Integer = CType(octets(octet - 1), Integer)

    If value >= 0 And value <= 255 Then
        ' Valid octet
    Else
        ' Invalid octet
    End If
Next
```

This way you can use `octet` to indicate which octet is invalid.

Comment: what does If Strings.StrComp(ipAddress, "localhost", CompareMethod.Text) = 0 Then
ipAddress = "127.0.0.1"
End If
also where did you get the ip 127.0.0.1 from

Comment: @Axiden see [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). This is a special case you might not need but sometimes users will connect to their machine so they use `localhost` which translates to `127.0.0.1`. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you out.